# What does it mean to return a reference?

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, return-type

I understand the concept of references in C++, and I understand what they do when used in function parameters, but I am still very much confused on how they work with return types.

For example, when used in parameters, this code:

```
int main (void) {
  int foo = 42;
  doit(foo);
}

void doit (int& value) {
  value = 24;
}
```

is similar to this code:

```
int main (void) {
  int foo = 42;
  doit(&foo);
}

void doit (int* value) {
  *value = 24;
}
```

(knowing that the compiler will automatically put an asterisk in front of *value* every time it is used in the first code sample of *doit*, but in the latter you'd have to put the asterisk in yourself every time you try to use *value*)

So when used as a reference what does this next code (using reference in a return type) translate to? Does it return a pointer to an int? Or would it just return an int?

```
int main (void) {
  int* foo = /*insert useful place in memory*/;
  foo = doit(foo);
}

int& doit (int* value) {
  //insert useful code
}
```

Comment: It would return a reference to an int, A reference you can think of as a named pointer, but without all the raw power of a pointer. The big problem with all of that , returning a reference to an object that quite possibly is created on the stack is that your going to have some nasty memory issues when the function returns and the functions stack is cleaned up. So , just be aware that just because it's a reference, that dose NOT mean that you wont have memory issues, and with references, it's really worse because the memory issue is hidden.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but the best way to think of a reference is to think of it as another name for an object, or, as Luchian said, an *alias.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It means you return by reference, which is, at least in this case, probably not desired. It basically means the returned value is an alias to whatever you returned from the function. Unless it's a persistent object it's illegal.

For example:

```
int& foo () {
    static int x = 0;
    return x;
}

//...
int main()
{
    foo() = 2;
    cout << foo();
}
```

would be legal and print out `2`, because `foo() = 2` modifies the actual value returned by `foo`.

However:

```
int& doit () {
    int x = 0;
    return x;
}
```

would be illegal (well, accessing the returned value would), because `x` is destroyed when the method exits, so you'd be left with a dangling reference.

Returning by reference isn't common for free functions, but it is for methods returning members. For example, in the `std`, the `operator []` for common containers return by reference. For example, accessing a vector's elements with `[i]` returns an actual reference to that element, so `v[i] = x` actually changes that element.

Also, I hope that "is essentially equal to this code" means that they're semantically sort of (but not really) similar. Nothing more.

Comment: Thanks Luchian, that helped a lot! And yes, I meant "similar". I'll edit that for future references.

Comment: Just to help clear up, return by reference returns the address of whatever object you attempted to return. You obviously don't want to return the address of an object with local scope because the object will be destroyed when the function called is done, which will leave you with a dangling reference (which would in turn may cause a use-after-free bug). Therefore, a good use of return by reference would be, as Luchian said, when returning a member.

Comment: @MrMeganFox returning by reference doesn't return the address, it returns an alias.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: no it returns a reference, not an alias.  References are usually implemented by using machine addresses under the hood.

Comment: @ChrisDodd a reference is an "alias" of the object it refers to - a different name for the same object.

Comment: The object doesn't need to be persistent, the lifetime of the object needs to be greater than the function scope, which can, for example be via lifetime extension.

Answer (score 4):

It means that you return a pointer to the memory address where the correspondent data is, instead of the very data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this code (to make it comparable to the first example) :

```
int main (void) {
  int* foo = /*insert useful place in memory*/;
  *foo = doit(foo);
}

int& doit (int* value) {
  *value = 24;
  return *value;
}
```

The `int&` is not really useful as a return type in this case, because it provides access to the variable in memory (of which you pass the pointer to the function).

> Does it return a pointer to an int? Or would it just return an int?

No, it returns a reference to an int. If you want, you can look at it as a pointer which can not be `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the best way to know the answer is to have a try...

Your codes will not pass type check, because doit will return a reference of int while you accept the return value as a pointer of int.

You can have a look at this:

```c
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int& doit (int* value) {
    value[0] = 3;
    return value[4];
}
int main (void) {
  int* foo = new int[10];
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    foo[i] = i;
  int& bar = doit(foo);
  cout<<bar<<endl;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      cout<<foo[i]<<" ";
  cout<<endl;
  bar = 12;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      cout<<foo[i]<<" ";
  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The variable "bar" will accept the return value, and it can be used change the content of "foo". As is mentioned by Luchian, it maybe dangerous to return a reference from the function, because the later codes might modify a value which is in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful example is operator overloading.

```
class vec2 {
public:
     vec2 operator+(const vec2& right_hand_side){
          return vec2(*this) += right_hand_side;
     }
     vec2& operator+=(const vec2& right_hand_side){
          x += right_hand_side.x;
          y += right_hand_side.y;
          return *this;
     }
 public:
 int x;
 int y;
}
```

In this example we have a vec2 class that represents a 2D vector. Now we defined two operators for this class, +, and +=. We want the + operator to return a copy of a vec2 to avoid a case where adding two operands results in changing the value of the operands.

```
vec2 a(1, 1);
vec2 b(5, 5);
vec2 c;
c = a + b;
```

Here, we want to assign *c* to (*a* + *b*), without affecting the values of *a* or *b*. However, in the case of the += operator, we want the operation to affect the object that is calling this operator, that object being one of the operands.

```
vec2 c(2, 2);
c += a; // c = (3, 3) a = (1, 1)
```

So, we can return a reference to the object we want affected by the operation. If we did not return a reference, both values would be copied in place. If we made both operators return a reference, then any + operation between two vec2s would affect the operands.

For example, if we changed

```
vec2& operator+(const vec2 right_hand_side){
     return *this += right_hand_side;
}
```

did the same operation,

```
c = a + b; // c = (6, 6), a = (6, 6)
```

*c* would be set to (6, 6), but so would *a*, since we would be returning a reference in the + operator.

A little clarification if that was confusing, but with operator overloading we the object that calls the operator is the left hand operand so when we do **a + b**, *a* is the ***this** that we are referring to, and the vec2 reference we are returning.