# What does the & operator do when used in operator overloading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having a c++ exam tomorrow, but the course lacks good learning material, so i couldn't find what the `&` operator does when used like this.

```
type operator*();
```

and

```
type &operator*();
```

It is used often in the example codes, but with no explanation. Are there return types where `&` has to be used, or is it connected to unary and/or binary operators?

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718465/what-does-it-mean-to-return-a-reference

Comment: @NathanOliver i've already checked that post, but i couldn't find my answer in the comments

Comment: It might be a matter of style, but imho the only correct way to write it is `type& operator*();`

Comment: Review the section of your C++ reference manual about "references" and "pointers".

Comment: You might have looked into this earlier than the day before the exam, no?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes and this question demonstrates _exactly_ why that is

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well it wasn't a huge blind spot in my c++ knowledge, only a small misunderstanding due to the poor teaching skills of my instructor. I had to self teach c++ because the class was the teacher thinking what she should write or debugging it, and could not explain why she wrote what she wrote. Probably excellent programmer, but horrible teacher.

Comment: @DomonkosKertész Good luck tomorrow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type &operator*();
```

The `&` has nothing to do with `operator*()` it's making the return value a reference to `type`.

That's why I like:

```
type& operator*();
```

better.

Comment: That clears it up, my instructor wrote it like this, thats why I thought that it is related to the operator.