# returning a pointer to a reference type function

Tags: c++

so I'm currently learning cpp (for fun at my own pace), specifically functions.
and i got a little confused, this is kinda beginner stuff
and it sometimes takes a little more time for me to understand..
i'm having a little hard time every time it comes to messing around with pointers and references
as things get more complicated the more i learn cpp.

i got this function, that confused me a bit:

```
int &get(int *arry, int index) { return arry[index]; }
```

`int &get` is a function of type `int` reference.
so i must return a reference.. (`&`)
does this means i'm returning a pointer ? but not dereferencing it ?
so the fact that i'm not dereferencing 'arry' means that i'm returning
the address of `arry[index]` ?
if so than address of the the reference operator are not the same

i may need a little order here.
thanks in advance.

Comment: "Does this mean I'm returning a pointer?" - No, see [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable).

Comment: A reference (`int &`) is a reference.  It might be implemented as a pointer but does not have to be, and using that analogy can lead to more confusion later.  The function returns a reference to the array element  `arry[index]`.  Which allows expressions like `get(my_array, 42) = 17;`

Comment: The return type `int&` means you return a reference to an `int`. If you've got a pointer to the first element of an array, applying the `[]` operator to it with an operand `index` yields a reference to the `(index+1)`th element of the array. E.g. you could write the following without having a function involved `int index = 2; int numbers[5] {1, 2,3, 4, 5}; int* arry = numbers; int& thirdElement = arry[index];` and `thirdElement` is a reference to the element containing 3 in `numbers`.

Comment: _"... if so than address of the the reference operator are not the same..."_:- lots of keywords and operators in C++ have multiple meanings;  eg `&` for reference and address-of, [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static) is used in multiple contexts, [`noexecpt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/noexcept) is both an operator and a specifier.

Comment: [What does it mean to return a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718465/what-does-it-mean-to-return-a-reference)